# Unable to get a container to use glusterfs running through convoy on Rancher

Tags: glusterfs, rancher

I have completed the installation as per [the tutorial on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LESPaJ9_DHE&feature=youtu.be) - Installed glusterfs and convoy gluster via the catalogue

However when I try to start a container that utilises glusterfs it fails to start. It completes all the usual stages such networking etc but then is just stuck the state of `Starting (Starting)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case the problem turned out that I needed to enter `convoy-gluster` as the storage driver rather than `convoy` as in the tutorial.